# Sync Framework, records not deleted on local server when deleting on remote and using filter template

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I setup sync framework 2.1 and I managed to sync between local and remote server ok. I use a template to filter by branch_id and I am able to bring proper records from branch (remote server) to local.
Everything works fine, I can add or edit records on any of the servers and then sync (on local) and the records are updated on both just fine.
The problem comes when I delete records on remote they are not deleted on local, curiously when I delete on local, records are actually deleted on server just fine.

If I remove the filter template everything works 100% ok, but I need to filter records by branch_id as it will take more time to download all records from other branches and that are not necessary to have.

**Is it the filter not allowing de deletion of records on local?**

**why is this hapenning even if deleted records are from the same branch_id?**

**Is there a way that when records are deleted allow the framework to handle it as witouth filters?**

For those who know how it works this is the basic scenario of the code:

1 - I create the template with the filter column by branch_id

2 - I create the local provisioning

3 - I create the remote provisioning and this is where I populate the template just created and apply the branch_id parameter, the scope name here can be "sectionNameScope_2075", "sectionNameScope_2076" and so on.

**This is the error scenario:**

1 - I can create or edit records on local or remote and everything works fine.

2 - I can delete records on local and everything works fine to.

3 - When I delete records on remote and when I sync the records are not being deleted on local, even when they have the same branch_id (local and remote)

Edit: One recomendation was to override the SelectingChanges event in the orchestrator but I do not know how to achieve so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I was setting the parameter in the template instead of using [side] I was using [base], thus causing this strange behaviour. 
I do not know why I worked fine with base instead of side even when you look at the sp_select_changes stored procedure and find that base is the main table alias, but because of that I did not suspected that was the issue.

```
// changed this
remoteServerProvisionTemplate.Tables["users"].FilterClause = "[base].[branch_id] = @branch_id";

// to this
remoteServerProvisionTemplate.Tables["users"].FilterClause = "[side].[branch_id] = @branch_id";
```